# After removing bootcamp partition, booting the mac it says insert bootable media and press any key?

Tags: macos, bootcamp, startup

so I had to remove my bootcamp partition because I was running low on osx Sierra space and I didn't need the Windows partition. But when I boot the mac I get an error

> No bootable device -- insert boot disk and press any key

My guess is that there is still some sort of a Windows boot manager on a partition, but I can't see it in Diskutil GUI or when pressing Alt on startup, or in the startup disk. Currently, the only wat to boot to macOS is to hold down Alt then -> Macintosh HD,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before selecting `Macintosh HD` in the Mac Startup Manager, hold down the <kbd>control</kbd> key. The straight arrow will become a circular arrow. This will make Sierra the default.

You can also make the Sierra the default, by selecting `Macintosh HD` from the Startup Disk pane of System Preferences.